# Hodrick and Prescott (HP) filter in R

Tags: r, time-series, filter

I'm applying the HP filter to time series data to remove the cyclical component of a time series (TS) from raw data. Data do have a yearly frequency.
I write in R:

```
lambda=100 #penalty term
cycle= hpfilter(v1,freq=lambda)$cycle
```

where `v1` is my TS data. In this way, I get the cyclical component.

Do you agree with me that is common practice to set $\lambda=100$ when you deal with annual data?

Comment: The literature appears to say otherwise.  See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodrick%E2%80%93Prescott_filter#The_equation) for instance.  This may be more a matter of practice in macroeconomics than a statistical question: statistics cannot tell you anything about how annual data might differ from data collected for other time periods.

Comment: Actually, the Wikipedia page says that it's common practice to set $\lambda=100$

Comment: Hi: I've never read it ( I've never used the HP filter ), but you probably should read this. https://www.nber.org/papers/w23429

Comment: @mlofton thanks for the info

Comment: Hamilton is a well respected time series person so definitely what he says shouldn't be taken lightly. At the same time, I'm sure Hodrick and Prescott are well respected also so who knows. Maybe Hodrick and Prescott have a rejoinder to Hamilton's paper ?